Is the idea of having a login shell and a non-login shell merely a way of making user preferences?
Scouring the internet about the difference between a login shell and a non-login shell, it turns out that the ultimate difference is merely the files that are being sourced. A login shell sources some files, and a non-login shell sources some different files.
So that's the definition. But then, so what? What is the main point or idea why there is a login shell and why there is a non-login shell? What can you do in a login shell that you cannot do in a non-login shell and vice versa?
The way I see it is that the purpose of a login shell is to let users customize their shell environment, while the purpose of a non-login shell is to have like a "default" uncustomized shell environment. Pretty much like the idea of having "user preference". Is this correct?

The idea of login shell and non-login shell is like using a desktop GUI with with a user account and using it with a Guest account.
In a desktop GUI, each user may have a different wall paper, shortcut icons, settings, etc. from each other user. Each user sees their own desktop environment when they login. This corresponds to a login shell in CLI.
A non login shell is like a Guest account in a desktop GUI. When you use a Guest account, you see a default, uncustomized desktop environment. When you use a non-login shell, you see a default, uncustomized shell environment.
So yes, the idea is basically to allow having user preferences.

I'm afraid this is completely wrong. Non-login interactive shells are the most common shell you use on your machine. They are what you run each time you open a new terminal (on most systems, at least), and they absolutely load your user's default settings. If anything, non-login shells are where you expect your settings. Login shells sometimes don't load them (e.g. when you have your settings in bashrc or equivalent).
